Hide scrollbars in kibana7 vega charts(Elastic search 7)
I want to hide scrollbars from Kibana7 (ES7) Vega charts . Found no solution to do so . Please suggest some ways to achieve the same .

As shown in attached image , Vertical scroll bars keep appearing even after resizing the boxes bigger . Please suggest settings to hide these scroll bars .
I tried to use below solution but did not work .

